# select the number of records to show mvc 5

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, fetch

I am creating a web app in which i have `6000` employees and i want to show all the employees on a table in my web app,

record is very large in number thats why it is taking too much time to show me the data

here is my web service

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public void showrecd()
        {
            List<object> employeedata = new List<object>();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.employeedetails order by id desc",con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                employeedata.Add(new{
                    id=dr["id"].ToString(),
                    empname=dr["empname"].ToString(),
                    address = dr["address"].ToString(),
                    jobdescrib =dr["jobdescrib"].ToString(),
                    brandname=dr["brandname"].ToString(),
                    location=dr["location"].ToString()
                });
            }
            var json = js.Serialize(employeedata);
            Context.Response.Write("{" + '"' + "info" + '"' + ":" + json + "}");
            con.Close();
        }
```

from here I am Fetching the data's,

now i want to make work much easier, i have taken a textbox

```
<input type="text" ng-model="records" ng-change="showrecordsasperthistextbox()"/>
```

now if if a user enter(500) in the above textbox, only 500 records must be fetched by the webservice
and if a user enters(1) only one record should be fetch by the webservice,

what and how i need to do this???

Comment: What is the code used for function `showrecordsasperthistextbox()`?

Comment: Go with Data Tables, it will provide all Feature search / Filter /  Pagination ect.

Comment: Pass user input value to select query as param. and append it in `TOP` clause. `select TOP (@P1) * from dbo.employeedetails order by id desc`

Comment: What if the user wants the first 50, and then the next 50? wouldn't that be the next step? Aren't you basically asking for a paging mechanism?

Comment: no i don't want to fetch all the data together i just want to fetch few data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's declare an int

```
Int number=20;// Declare this as dynamic
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top (cast('" + number + "' as int)) * from dbo.employeedetails order by id",con);
```

and now your sqlcommand

//If You are getting error in `(top('"+number+"'))` this command

try this

```
(cast('"+number+"' as int))
```

let me know